# How to resolve fish: "Unable to open universal variable file '/': Permission denied"?

Tags: fish

Fish gives frequent warnings

```
error: Unable to open universal variable file '/': Permission denied
```

What causes this, and how can it be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Universal variables in fish are preserved across sessions, and must be stored on disk.
Typically they are stored in `/home/user/.config/fish/fish_variables`

On my system, the permissions (ownership) of this file were not set correctly:

```
> ll fish_variables
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.4K Aug  7 15:00 fish_variables
```

Changing ownership resolved the problem:

```
chown user:user fish_variables
```